# Migrating JUnit JPA tests from Spring 2.5.5 to Spring 3.0.4

Tags: spring, jpa, junit4

Our project has just decided to migrate from Spring 2.5.5 to Spring 3.0.4.  In my original code, I had unit tests that looked like the following:

```
public class RequisitionDaoTest extends AbstractJpaTests
{

    public static String FAIL_MSG_UNEXPECTED_ERROR = "FAIL: Unexpected Error";

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        @Test
        public void testSomething ()
        {
          ...
        }
}
```

This worked just fine with Spring 2.5.5. Now with Spring 3.0.4, the AbstractJpaTests class has been deprecated.

The problem is that I can't seem to find what to use to replace it. I've seen several posts that show using something called *AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests*, but when I convert to using it, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4aec4aec] to prepare test instance [RequsitionDaoTest@5dcc5dcc]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RequsitionDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:608)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    ... 28 more
```

Since I'm using JPA, I don't have or need a DataSource bean for Spring.

So is there any direct analog for the AbstractJpaTests class in the new Spring, or should I just continue to uses the deprecated classes for now?

Thanks...

--Steve

Comment: Using deprecated classes is no bad thing, it just means that there's now an alternative preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @skaffman True, but when we migrate, I tend to try and remove deprecated stuff, since I know that at some point it's going to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that there is no analog to the *AbstractJpaTests* class in the new Spring. The new test class do not need to inherit any behavior from Spring to do their jobs. Its all handled by the annotations now.

So my class should actually look like this:

```
public class RequisitionDaoTest
{

    public static String FAIL_MSG_UNEXPECTED_ERROR = "FAIL: Unexpected Error";

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        @Test
        public void testSomething ()
        {
          ...
        }
}
```

In addition, you need to include the assertion functions from Spring, since they're not included by the *AbstractJpaTests* class. The import looks like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.